# how to pass variables future function to extend statefulwidget

Tags: flutter

in my code in HomeeScreen class I call **Future function** , In that future function fecth data from API and display in console nicely. **print(datas[0].field2Value);** this is the code line.And aslo that is the boolean value I want to get that value to **class _HomeeScreenState extends State** and deaclare to a bool variable. like this
**bool field2Value = datas[0].field2;**
but then show this error.

code

```
class _HomeeScreenState extends State<HomeeScreen> {
  Timer? timer;
  Future<List<DataList>>? future;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => isDoctorActive(widget.id));
  }

  bool field2Value = datas[0].field2Value;

  final String url = 'https://exampleapi.com/api/calls/?check=';
  Future<List<DataList>> isDoctorActive(String id) async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url + id));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("apicall : " + id);
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);

      Map<String, dynamic> body = json['data'];
      List<DataList> datas = [DataList.fromJson(body)];
      print(datas[0].field2Value);

      return datas;
    } else {
      throw ('cannot fetch data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: field2Value ? joinVideoRoom : null, child: Text("Join")),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> joinVideoRoom() async {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NextScreen(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the entire `_HomeeScreenState` class. Where are you defining `datas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just accept another argument in your function? meaning:

```dart
isActive(String id, myArgument)
```

```dart
class _HomeeScreenState extends State<HomeeScreen> {
    
 
bool field2Value = datas[0].field2;
final String url = 'https://exampleapi.com/api/calls/?check=';

Future<List<DataList>> isActive(String id, field2) async {
  ....
  print(field2)
   
  }
```

Comment: At the "bool field2Value = datas[0].field2;" show this error "Undefined name 'datas' ".

Comment: @DasunDola can you edit your question to include the full code?

Comment: @DasunDola I don't see any `datas` in your code..

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> body = json['data'];
      List<DataList> datas = [DataList.fromJson(body)];
      print(datas[0].field2Value);

      return datas;

Comment: in tehe future function i return datas